# What causes a PCI ID to change

Tags: kernel, udev, pci

When running `lspci` on my RHEL 7.2 box I noticed my Ethernet Adapters changed PCI bus IDs.  In the example below it changed from "02:00.x" to "03:00.x".

1. What might have caused this?
2. Is there a way to force it to a
   specific address?

Before:

```
[root@rhel:~]# lspci | grep Ethernet
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
02:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
```

Current:

```
[root@rhel:~]# lspci | grep Ethernet
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
03:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
```

Comment: I have to ask why you want to have it on a specific ID - what are you trying to accomplish? It might be possible to achieve that goal in some other way, as I suspect the PCI IDs can't be forced.

Answer (score 5):

All but the root bus (which is typically a platform bus, e.g. ACPI on PCs) are bridged off the root bus, and their order depends on enumeration.

Now normally bus enumeration is mostly deterministic as the order in which devices on the bus are found is normally static, but there is no guarantee for that, and when two bus bridges are chained, enumeration is in parallel:

1. begin enumerating ACPI bus
2. find PCIe bridge 1 on ACPI bus, assign bus ID 0
3. begin enumerating PCIe bus 0
4. find PCIe bridge 2 on ACPI bus, assign bus ID 1
5. find PCI bridge 1 on PCIe bus 0, assign bus ID 2
6. find PCIe bridge 3 on ACPI bus, assign bus ID 3

There is no ordering between the two enumeration threads, so the PCI bridge can get an ID of 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: Very interesting, but I don't understand how this answers my question.  If the bus enumeration is deterministic then why did my IDs change in the first place?  And if there is no ordering between threads, is it likely to change frequently on reboots?

Comment: The ordering on each bus is deterministic, but the buses form a hierarchy, and bus IDs are assigned in enumeration order. Nondeterminism starts once there are two layers (the ACPI->PCIe bridge, and the PCIe->PCI bridge). The bus numbers can change on every reboot, so if you want stable identifiers, use the full path (slot 1 of the bus hanging off slot 2 of the root bus).

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment so I guess an "Answer" will have to suffice.

Have you upgraded your system at all? Now I am by no means an expert in this, but if you add additional PCI/PCI slots to an existing PCI bus, then there is the "possibility" that the numbers can change I believe. I would much rather have made this a comment in case I was wrong, but I am sure someone will correct me if my knowledge is off.

Comment: You are correct, adding or removing physical hardware can change the PCI IDs.  I've also heard changing BIOS settings can sometimes change IDs.  I have not modified the hardware and I don't know what BIOS changes might change the IDs.

Comment: Probably not something you would have to worry about, but you could always open your computer up and "verify" nothing has been added to your system without your knowledge to be on the safe side.

Comment: http://h20565.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=254931&docId=emr_na-c01132845&lang=en-us&cc=us&docLocale=en_US

Comment: That is a link to a whitepaper created by Compaq. Very good read if you are interested in learning a more in depth knowledge of PCI. Although it is a bit dated so some things may not be fully correct and/or implemented by todays standards

Comment: thanks for the comments, I'm concerned about my PCI IDs changing because I have udev rules that assign an interface name based on the PCI ID.  When the ID changed my interfaces didn't come up and I can't log in (it's a headless remote system).